# Does an API Rate Limit see javascript requests as coming from the domain's IP, or the user's IP?

Tags: javascript, api, rate-limiting

An API has a rate limit based upon the number of hits from a certain IP address.

My requests are AJAX - so they're performed by a javascript living somewhere on a page.

Does the IP being rate limited appear as the client's or the site's?

Comment: The client, of course. Sure it doesn't limit by API key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since javascript is executed client side (aka in the browser) the request will show the client's IP (or any proxy).

Comment: That's what I thought. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The IP address the service provider can see would be the client (web browser) address.

But this is not necessarily what is being used for limiting. That could also be done by the API key or user account. Check your service agreements.